# enable javascript support for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pdt

how do I enable javascript support in eclipse pdt. I have aptana installed.
thx

Answer (score 3):

You can install JavaScript Development Tools (JSDT): http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer there are ways to ['help' Eclipse with JS](http://www.kajabity.com/2012/02/how-i-introduced-jsdoc-into-a-javascript-project-and-found-my-eclipse-outline/) using JsDoc.
One example is using `@memberOf` to help the outline.

Also add the [jshint eclipse plugin](http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/) to show problems detected by jsHint in the js editor.